# Gradle Build stuck at :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, apk

I build an app with react-native, and I'm trying to build a release apk with the command

`./gradlew assembleRelease`

but the build gets stuck when it reaches :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

example:

```
<=------------> 12% EXECUTING [29m 42s]
IDLE
IDLE
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
IDLE
```

if I build a debug version using `./gradlew assembleDebug`, the build completes within a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it on my machine. It was because of "Waiting for Watchman".

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
watchman shutdown-server
watchman watch-del-all
watchman --logfile=[Absolute path to another file]
```